# Spring Boot Serving .jsp <jar>

Tags: maven, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Playing around trying to wrap my head around Spring Boot i cant make the jsp pages display. Have the daos etc working so no probs there but i cant for the life of me make it display a simple jsp page (no data passed in, just a simple page)

Have read so many things around the jsp limitations but didnt really understand what to do to bypass them.

If someone can help out with what i am missing here please.

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.wtf4j</groupId>
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>webapp</name>
<description>WTF4J WebApp</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For serving jsp pages -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties** includes :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**ProductController.java:**

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/newproduct")
    public String write() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[Project Structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT96i.png)

I have tried adding jsps in both /resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp as well as /webapp/WEB-INF/view

**error**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=65077:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Alx\Desktop\webapp\target\classes;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.1.11\logback-classic-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.1.11\logback-core-1.1.11.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\log4j-over-slf4j\1.7.25\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.17\snakeyaml-1.17.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jdbc\8.5.27\tomcat-jdbc-8.5.27.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\8.5.27\tomcat-juli-8.5.27.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.0.12.Final\hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.1.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.0.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.21.0-GA\javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.0.Final\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\5.0.12.Final\hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\1.11.10.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-1.11.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\1.13.10.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-1.13.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-orm-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.25\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-aspects-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-validator\5.3.6.Final\hibernate-validator-5.3.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\1.1.0.Final\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.8.10\jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0\jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.10\jackson-core-2.8.10.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.45\mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.14.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\1.5.10.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.27\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-annotations-api\8.5.27\tomcat-annotations-api-8.5.27.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.27\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.27.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.27\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.27.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-jasper\8.5.27\tomcat-embed-jasper-8.5.27.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\ecj\3.12.3\ecj-3.12.3.jar;C:\Users\Alx\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar" com.wtf4j.webapp.WebappApplication

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

2018-02-11 15:53:17.055  INFO 9036 --- [           main] com.wtf4j.webapp.WebappApplication       : Starting WebappApplication on AlxDskTp with PID 9036 (C:\Users\Alx\Desktop\webapp\target\classes started by Alx in C:\Users\Alx\Desktop\webapp)
2018-02-11 15:53:17.056  INFO 9036 --- [           main] com.wtf4j.webapp.WebappApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-11 15:53:17.124  INFO 9036 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17211155: startup date [Sun Feb 11 15:53:17 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-11 15:53:18.273  INFO 9036 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51114ec9] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-02-11 15:53:18.869  INFO 9036 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-02-11 15:53:18.884  INFO 9036 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-02-11 15:53:18.885  INFO 9036 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.27
2018-02-11 15:53:19.063  INFO 9036 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2018-02-11 15:53:19.069  INFO 9036 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-02-11 15:53:19.069  INFO 9036 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1947 ms
2018-02-11 15:53:19.147  INFO 9036 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2018-02-11 15:53:19.150  INFO 9036 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-02-11 15:53:19.494  INFO 9036 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-02-11 15:53:19.502  INFO 9036 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2018-02-11 15:53:19.545  INFO 9036 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2018-02-11 15:53:19.546  INFO 9036 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-02-11 15:53:19.546  INFO 9036 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-02-11 15:53:19.570  INFO 9036 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-02-11 15:53:19.627  INFO 9036 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2018-02-11 15:53:19.853  INFO 9036 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2018-02-11 15:53:19.890  INFO 9036 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-02-11 15:53:20.067  INFO 9036 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.wtf4j.webapp.Controller.ProductController.write()
2018-02-11 15:53:20.072  INFO 9036 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-02-11 15:53:20.073  INFO 9036 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-02-11 15:53:20.121  INFO 9036 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17211155: startup date [Sun Feb 11 15:53:17 EET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-11 15:53:20.449  INFO 9036 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-02-11 15:53:20.488  INFO 9036 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-02-11 15:53:20.492  INFO 9036 --- [           main] com.wtf4j.webapp.WebappApplication       : Started WebappApplication in 3.664 seconds (JVM running for 4.233)
2018-02-11 15:53:28.597  INFO 9036 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-02-11 15:53:28.597  INFO 9036 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-02-11 15:53:28.618  INFO 9036 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms
2018-02-11 15:53:28.708 ERROR 9036 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'] with root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1266) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

Comment: I believe there are some problems when using jsp with boot, especially if you deploy the app as executable jar - it's easier to use thymeleaf or other template engine in that case. Have you tried packaging the app as a war file instead of jar?

Comment: I have found JSP Limitations https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations that is probably what you are refering to. I couldnt however understand how to overcome this. Packaging as war involves changing the <packaging>jar</packaging> to war? Is there somethign else to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

Changed the packaging in the pom.xml to `<packaging>war</packaging>`

Then added the following bean to WebappApplication.java Class (made sure it points to the correct folder which after the latest changes is **/webapp/view/** jsp's are in here):

```
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/view/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
}
```

And it works. Don't really understand why but its a start.

Answer (score 0):

I think, everything is correct expect jsp path, you can try to load all jsp files to /resources/WEB-INF/jsp/ this folder.

PS>I did not see WEB-INF folder in your resources folder you can create it manually

Comment: Thanks for that man, but still wont work. Exactly the same errors. I have been looking into this for the past 8 hours and its driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather dated post but for others who may view it:

The key to the accepted solution is the change to `war` packaging.

However, the practice of putting `JSP` outside of the `.../webapp/WEB-INF/` folder is not advised since a user can access those files directly from the web browser if they are not under the `WEB-INF` folder.  Users having direct access to raw JSP is considered a security leak.